# AngularJS $state.go pass always empty valure for parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I've tried to pass one parameter white $stete.go.

#### ROUTER

```
$stateProvider.state('login.signin', {
    url: '/signin',
    params: {
        login_event: ''
    },
    templateUrl: "assets/views/login_login.html",
    title: 'Login',
    resolve: loadSequence('moment', 'userLoginCtrl')
});
```

#### CALLING

```
$state.go('login.signin', { login_event: "session_expired"});
```

#### TEST

```
console.log('toParams: ');
console.log(toParams);

console.log('fromParams: ');
console.log(fromParams);

console.log('$stateParams: ');
console.log($stateParams);

console.log('$state.params: ');
console.log($state.params);
```

Even if I pass a value in calling, the value I get in "toParams" is always the default value.

I've tried many many time to get a value, but "toParams" have only the default value.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current implementation(shorthand implementation) of `params` object, which will not consider the parameter pass from the `$stateParms`, it will default value of `login_event` to `''`. You should change your `params` object implementation so that default value would be `''` like `value: ''` if its not passed.

[**Docs Link**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

**Code**

```
params: {
    login_event: {
       value: ''
    }
},
```